# Access Fortran custom type attributes by default

Tags: fortran, fortran2003, custom-type, fortran2008

is it possible with modern Fortran (90, 2003 or even 2008) to have a custom type where one of the attributes would be accessed by default:

```
program test
    use iso_fortran_env
    type MYTYPE_t
        real(real64) :: data
    end type MYTYPE_t

    type(MYTYPE_T) :: test
    real(real64) :: foo

    ! This works
    test%data = 5.0
    ! Is there a way to be able things like this:
    test = 5.0
    print*, sqrt(test)

    foo = test + 3
end program
```

Comment: Does defined assignment cover your requirements?

Comment: It somehow does the job. But the issue is that one would then have to override all the default operators and it won't work with fortran intrinsics.

Comment: It will work, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must overload all the possible assignments, operators and intrinsics. Yes, it is a lot of work. No, there is no magic faster way that would cause automatic conversion in all contexts.

```
module types
    use iso_fortran_env

    implicit none

    type MYTYPE_t
        real(real64) :: data
    contains
        procedure assign
        procedure add
        generic :: assignment(=) => assign
        generic :: operator(+) => add
    end type MYTYPE_t

    interface sqrt
      procedure sqrt_MTYPE
    end interface

contains

    subroutine assign(l,r)
      class(MYTYPE_t), intent(out) :: l
      real(real32), intent(in) :: r
      l%data = r
    end subroutine

    real(real64) function sqrt_MTYPE(x)
      type(MYTYPE_t), intent(in) :: x
      sqrt_MTYPE = sqrt(x%data)
    end function

    real(real64) function add(x, y)
      class(MYTYPE_t), intent(in) :: x
      integer, intent(in) :: y

      add = x%data + y
    end function
end module types

program test_program
    use types

    implicit none

    type(MYTYPE_T) :: test
    real(real64) :: foo

    ! This works
    test%data = 5.0
    ! Is there a way to be able things like this:
    test = 5.0
    print*, sqrt(test)

    foo = test + 3
end program
```

test:

```
> gfortran override3.f90 
> ./a.out 
   2.2360679774997898
```

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know about things like `sqrt_MTYPE` could work. Thanks